# *args и **kwargs в декораторах

Tags: python

судя по записи `f(*args, **kwargs)` и сигнатуре передаваемой функции `f(a)`, я передаю лишние аргументы
почему не возникает ошибка?

```
def g(f):
  def w(*args, **kwargs):
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  return w

@g
def f(a):
  print(a)
```

Comment: Потому что вы не передаёте лишние аргументы.

Comment: разве? ведь если я не передам именованных аргументов то kwargs == {}, и это эквивалентно, например, f(3, {}). Что я недопонимаю?

Comment: Нет, если kwargs пустой, то он не добавляет никакие аргументы и это будет эквивалентно f(3)